# App compatibility issues

Tags: android

My app displays a popup(Custom made) which has two textviews on the screen. On Android 2.3, the bottom textview appears messed up (width is dramatically reduced) but the top is fine. How can I address this issue? I cant seem to make any changes without affecting versions above 2.3

Comment: can you post the code that you are using? and perhaps a screenshot of how it turns out?

Comment: Mind posting the xml layout and a screen shot of what you get. It would be helpful to understand what is happening. If you are supporting multiple screen layouts, take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html